# Android Checkbox doesn't return right value

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I'm using custom listview that has checkbox. And I want to know checkbox is checked or not. So I used getCheckedItemPositions() to get checked_info. If I set "android:clickable = "true" ", checkboxs don't return result. However if I set "android:clickable = "false" ", nothing changes in view but checkboxs return their checked information. What is problem? Bottom codes are my method that use getCheckedItemPostions() and XML code of custom listiview.

```
public void deleteButton(View v)
{
    int i,count;
    count = mMyAdapter.mItems.size();
    SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
}





<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:checkable="true"



            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_weight="4"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="10pt"
                android:text="name.." />


            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="12pt"
                android:text="name.." />


        </LinearLayout>


        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
            android:layout_width="6dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:text="Toggle"
            android:textOff="Off"
            android:textOn="On" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_checkbox_control.htm" Check this once. If u didn't get answer inform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement setOnCheckedChangeListener because by setting clickable false will stop the execution cycle once it is clicked after that you cant get updated value so make it true but implement setOnCheckedChangeListener to save state of your checkbox as checked or not by creating a boolean variable for each of your checkbox. Then it will work.

Follow this tutorial to implement onCheckedChangeListener:

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-checkbox-example/

Comment: How to implement setOnCHeckedChangeListener on checkbox in listiview?

Comment: Also if it works for you dont forget to mark my post as answer.Happy Coding bro :)